# insert into table values: from another table and one value is identity

Tags: sql, sql-insert, identity

I heva table data
i want to insert to rhis table all the records from another table, but the first coulmn should be identity

i try this:

```
 INSERT INTO data (record_num ,Code,cust)
select (???,Code,cust)
from MERGE
```

but i dont know how to insert this identity value (because its not comming from MERGE table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you need the identity value to be the same from the other table, in which case use:

```
-- SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON.  
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE_NAME ON;  
GO
```

remember to put it off after.

Answer (score 0):

You just leave it out.  It gets assigned automatically:

```
 INSERT INTO data (Code, cust)
    select Code, cust
    from MERGE
```